# Does $A,B\in M_{n\times n}$ both lower triangular imply simultaneous triangularization?

Tags: matrices

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Simultaneous_triangularisability) states that two matrices are simultaneously triangularisable if there exists a basis under which they are both upper triangular.

By this I take it that if we can make both matrices upper triangular then they are simultaneously triangularisable.

My Question is: Are $A$ and $B$ simultaneously triangularisable if we can make both matrices lower triangular, instead of upper triangular as in the above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is lower triangular under the basis $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, then it is upper triangular under the basis $x_n, \ldots, x_1$, i.e. the same basis vectors in reverse order.